# How can I print "hello world" every 34 minutes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, timer

How can I print "hello world" every 34 minutes in python? Right now I'm grabbing the system time, comparing it to my last recording time, looping around (which is a pain for 24 hour clocks), rinse and repeat. Is there a nice and easy way to do this.

To put simply, how would you loop code this code every 34 minutes:

print("Task to do every 34 minutes")

Comment: Using `time.sleep` as noted in the answers is probably the option you want, but if for some reason you need to actually keep track of the time (for logging, for example), you can use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` so you don't have to worry about the 24 hour clock question.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `time` module:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    print("Task to do every 34 minutes")

    sleep(60 * 34)  # argument is seconds
```

Comment: You would either need to call this as `sleep(60 * 34)`, or do `import time`.  Right now you will get a `NameError` about `time`.

Comment: Yes you are correct - I forgot I imported sleep that way :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a solution:

```
import time

while True:
    print "hello world"
    time.sleep(2040)
```

Sleep takes argument as number of seconds so 60*34 = 2040.

Comment: Did you mean 'from time import sleep'?

Comment: Ha! The answers seem to have made opposite mistakes.